# What are the "Notices" in this question's revision history?

Tags: support, specific-question

As I was looking through the revision history on [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/95780/revisions), I saw some strange things I haven't seen before. Here is a "transcript" of sorts (ignoring edits):

> **Question Unprotected** by Dennis
>
> **Notice removed** Improve details by Dennis
>
> **Notice added** Improve details by Sickboy
>
> **Notice removed** Improve details by Community
>
> **Bounty Ended** with Geno Racklin Asher's answer chosen by Community
>
> **Question Protected** by Community
>
> **Notice added** Improve details by TheBitByte
>
> **Bounty Started** worth 50 reputation by TheBitByte

Comment: The second notice corresponds to a bounty that was added by the OP and removed by Dennis (it basically changed the challenge entirely). Not sure why no bounty shows up there; it might have to do with the fact that it was removed by a mod.